# How to put the inputs in array?

Tags: arduino-uno, array, rfid

I face a problem and I really need help.
For my Arduino project, I'm using RFID reader with tags.
The story is, I have a desired arrangement for the cards and I defined it as an array called desired[]= {.... , .... ,....}
Then, I want my RFID reader to read the real sequence of the cards and Arduino will tell me if the sequence is right or wrong.
My real problem is, how to put the input which will come from the reader in my empty array real[2];
My code is:

```
#include <SPI.h> //// Library
#include <MFRC522.h> // Library
constexpr uint8_t RST_PIN = 9;     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
 constexpr uint8_t SS_PIN = 10;     // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
 MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance
String Desired[]={ "f01ca379" ,"60d7a1a5" , "64d7a3a6"};
String Real[2];

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);                                           // Initialize 
serial communications with the PC
SPI.begin();                                                  // Init SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init();                                              // Init MFRC522 card
 }

   String readUID() {
  String readUID = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
     readUID = readUID + (mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? "0" : "");
    readUID = readUID + String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
          }
            mfrc522.PICC_HaltA(); 
       return readUID;
      }


void loop() {
 if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
return; }
 if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
return; }
String UID = readUID();
if (UID == "f778f19"){
******************************************
******************************************
     }
 }
```

I used f01ca379 card as a master card only to start the loop.
in the {*************} I need to complete the code in order to save the input in my Real Array, then to compare it with the desired array and decide if the real arrangement matched with the desired one.with tags

Comment: why do you need to put the scanned card number into an array? .....  why don't you simply compare the card numbers as you scan them?

Comment: The first problem is, how to decide the number of card scanned without using an array?  Because I want the reader to stop after scanning 3 cards, and do the process again.  Also, what command I have to use in order to compare without an array? Because when RFID reader scan the first item, i want to compare it with first number in array, second time of scanning, comparing with second number in desired array.... Etc.  Please help me how it comes?

Comment: there is no `number of card scanned` ..... there is  `number of card being checked` ...... why would you continue to check all three cards if the first one does not match?  ........ do this with playing cards first (or with pieces of paper)

Comment: For my project, I need to check all three cards ... even if the first one doesn't match, I need to check the rest of them, and that's the problem. Also, in the real case it's not only 3, I just chose 3 to start writing the logic.